# I am trying to build a summary data frame using totals from another data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So I have all the data points formatted into a table where I can now start to summarise my findings.

```
           home_goals   away_goals  result  home_points away_points
2006-2007      1            1          D         1          1
2006-2007      1            1          D         1          1
2006-2007      2            1          H         3          0
2006-2007      2            1          H         3          0
2006-2007      3            0          H         3          0
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
2019 - 2020    0            2          A         0          3
2019 - 2020    5            0          H         3          0
2019 - 2020    1            3          A         0          3
2019 - 2020    3            1          H         3          0
2019 - 2020    1            1          D         1          1
```

My objective is to collate this into a new data frame that summarises each season under the following columns:

```
Season_breakdown = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['Season','Matches Played','Home 
                                            Wins','Draws','Away Wins', 'Home Points',
                                            'Away Points'])
```

My current solution is to run for something like this

```
  index_count = pd.Index(data_master.index).value_counts()

  index_count
```

That outputs:

```
 2007-2008         380
 2013-2014         380
 2010-2011         380
 2017-2018         380
 2015-2016         380
 2016-2017         380
 2009-2010         380
 2014-2015         380
 2012-2013         380
 2006-2007         380
 2018-2019         380
 2011-2012         380
 2008-2009         380
 2019 - 2020 P1    288
 2019 - 2020 P2     92
```

and then hardcode the results into a new data variable which I can incorporate into my Season_breakdown and repeat similar steps to collate the information for home wins (by season) away wins (by season) home points (by season) away points (by season).

The aim is to have something along the lines of;

```
  Season      MatchesPlayed  HomeWins      Draws      AwayWins   HomePoints    AwayPoints
  2006-2007        380     (sum H 6/7) (sum D 6/7) (sum H 6/7) (sum h_points)(sum a_points)
  2007-2008        380     (sum H 7/8) (sum D 7/8) (sum H 7/8) (sum h_points)(sum a_points)
  2008-2009        380     (sum H 8/9) (sum D 8/9) (sum H 8/9) (sum h_points)(sum a_points)
  2009-20010       380     (sum H 9/10)(sum D 9/10)(sum H 9/10)(sum h_points)(sum a_points)
```

Etc.

I feel like there is a far more robust way to approach this and was hoping for some insight.

Thanks

Comment: I don't think you need an intermediate dataframe for counts. Just use ```pandas.pivot_table``` and you can use the ```aggfunc``` parameter to count some values and sum others.

Comment: Thanks for the insight eric, just to clarify I would use the pandas.pivot_table and then adjust for each of the conditions or could i capture all the conditions in one table?

Answer (score 0):

You have multi level aggregations. Points are aggregated at the season level, while Wins/Draws are aggregated at the combined season / result level. So one option is to aggregate the result in multiple steps and then concatenate / join the results:

```
season_points = df.groupby(level=[0]).agg({'home_points': 'sum', 'away_points': 'sum'})

season_count = df.groupby(level=[0]).result.count().rename('MatchesPlayed').to_frame()

season_results = pd.crosstab(df.index, df.result).rename(
    columns={'A': 'AwayWins', 'D': 'Draws', 'H': 'HomeWins'})
season_results.index.name = None

agg_df = pd.concat([season_count, season_results, season_points], axis=1) \
  .rename(columns={'home_points': 'HomePoints', 'away_points': 'AwayPoints'})
print(agg_df)

#             MatchesPlayed  AwayWins  Draws  HomeWins  HomePoints  AwayPoints
#2006-2007                5         0      2         3          11           2
#2019 - 2020              5         2      1         2           7           7
```

[Working example](https://uscript.co/public/Google_108617488638529745626/python/fe8d9199.py)